# Automated test works locally but fails on browser stack due to not clicking

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Created a test case that passes locally then fails when running in browser stack. The root cause is that an element is not being clicked. When I run this locally the element is always clicked. Using capybara, rspec and ruby to write the tests. The reason the test fails is because the next step is to click an element. Since the drop down is never clicked, the element is not found, it is in the drop down.

Here is an image of the error

[image]

I have tried a few different methods for clicking that will work locally but not solve the issue. Running on OSX Chrome, Mojave version 73.

Some code that I have tried:

```
  def language_dropdown
    find('div', id:'user_locale_chzn').click
  end
```

```
  def language_dropdown
    within(:css, "div#user_locale_chzn") do
      find('a', class: 'chzn-single').trigger(:click)
    end
  end
```

```
  def language_dropdown
    within(:css, "div#user_locale_chzn") do
      locale = find('a', class: 'chzn-single')
      execute_script("arguments[0].click();", locale)
    end
  end
```

I expect that the language drop down element is clicked to expand options so the test can continue to run but this only happens locally and again does not work on browserstack.

Comment: Whne you say "not clicking" do you mean you get an error (if so add it to the question) or do you just mean the behavior you expect from the click isn't happening (if so add the following code that isn't seeing what you expect, and the error that generates).  Also please add the relevant portion of HTML you're working with.  Note: if you're testing an app/site you should never be using `trigger` or clicks triggered via `execute_script` - they do not replicate what a user could do on the page

Comment: @ThomasWalpole updated, thanks! The error I receive is the element is not found but that is because the drop down is never clicked

Comment: Without knowing what other code is being run that error really doesn't tell much except that the click is happening (otherwise Capybara would have errored on the initial click), you're just not seeing the results of the click you expect. I would guess the answer by @Bodhish is correct and you're running in a different screen resolution/window size on browserstack than locally.

Comment: Are you running headless on browserstack and with a real browser locally?  I've seen that cause discrepancies, that and window size.  If you can't get the click to open the dropdown, you might try putting focus on it and sending a down arrow key.  It's a workaround, but I've used it for really stubborn/flaky dropdowns.